# how to add dynamically new row to already existed table with controls in asp.net c# in Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add new row when click on some button i.e (plus image), [the row must contain these fields when clicked on image button,I'm trying to do this but does not get with the same as it is i want please help me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQM9h.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Client side OR Server side?

Comment: What kind of Row? To a database, GridView, html table, DataTable?